# Paid Messages: Don't ask again

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

HOW DO I FIX IT? When I was texting my local radio station (which had a less than 7 digit number) my phone said this may add charges to your account  (aka may cost money). And my being quick pressed "never ask me again" then okay but instead I hit declined and it won't let me text any number that has less than 6 numbers and charges me. How do I fix it so I can again?

Answer (score 1):

In Android N;

Settings, Apps, Your messaging app, SMS App (below Memory), Special Access (bottom option),  Premium SMS access.

Alternatively - Settings, Search, "premium" or similar